# How can I build a unity UI component that is reusable across scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to build a UI modal in Unity that can be used across multiple scenes, how do I achieve this and later on probably build it as a stand-alone library people can use in their unity projects. Are there tutorials on this?

Comment: You mean [Prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html)?

Comment: @derHugo I dont think prefabs cuts it. Cause I want to design a form thats calls a specific url........meaning it would have not only the UI but also a C# script with all the predefined logic.

Comment: Yes .. and this is what Prefabs do. Stores a completely configured GameObject template including its attached Components(scripts) and parameters configured via the Unity Inspector in serialized fields (either `public` or `[SerializeField] private`). You can e.g. simply configure according URL as `const` or via the Inspector

Answer (score 2):

Explore this [repo](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UIElementsUniteCPH2019RuntimeDemo). It's usable, but experimental for now. UIElements are becoming a new standard for Unity, so there will be a preview package in a few weeks/month.

If you want to use current UI, you can create separate scenes for each reusable window and open them additive, passing parameters and callbacks to static methods, see my [example](https://pastebin.com/KPjUsz84)

Line

```
public class ResultLineEntity {
    public int Place;
    public readonly string Title;
    public readonly TimeSpan Time;
    public ResultLineEntity(string title, TimeSpan time, int? place = null) {
        if (place != null) Place = place.Value;
        Title = title;
        Time = time;
    }
}
```

Window

```
public class ResultsUi : MonoBehaviour {
    public static ResultLineEntity[] Lines
    {
        get => _lines;
        set
        {
            _lines = value;
            OnLinesChange?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    private static ResultLineEntity[] _lines;

    public static UnityEvent OnLinesChange { get; private set; } = new UnityEvent();

    [SerializeField] private Transform root;
    [SerializeField] private ResultLineUi prefab;

    private void Awake() {
        SetLines();
        OnLinesChange?.AddListener(SetLines);
    }

    public void SetLines() {
        if (Lines==null || Lines.Length < 1) return;

        foreach (var child in root.GetComponentsInChildren<ResultLineUi>()) {
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }

        var resultsOrdered = Lines.OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToArray();
        for (var index = 0; index < resultsOrdered.Length; index++) {
            var line = resultsOrdered[index];
            line.Place = index + 1;
            var currentLine = Instantiate(prefab, root);
            currentLine.SetLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
ResultsUi.Lines = lines;
SceneManager.LoadScene(ResultsSceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```